# Remove Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi to android stack overflow communities,

I want to remove the action bar which contain the title and the three dots. I have tried some of the solutions such as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` but, the app went crash.

Is there any possible other solution? Thanks

Comment: Please post your logcat and manifest.

Comment: you can do it using in your Activity class and Androidmanifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the nuclear option.

Replace

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

with

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

in all the `Activity`s where you don't want `ActionBar`.

And to remove the three-dots button, add

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

to your `Activity`.

Try this. This will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Activity` not `ActionBarActivity`. So `extends` your javaclass from `Activity`. For removing the three dots remove `onCreateOptionsMenu` method from your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Create Your code like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Enter this line android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" in Activity

Answer (score -1):

You just need to call function

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Tthis will hide action bar for you simply.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().hide()